# Unable to Save Pyspark job result to a single text file after using union on two Rdd

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have one text as a data source file which don't have header row I did some transformation on the rdd .After that i create a header rdd using parallelize ,And I perform a union with two rdd. I save my result to text file using saveasTextfile. Unfortunately the file is saved as 2 file one for heading and one for values. How can i save this two Rdd to single file.

Comment: your code please

Comment: ratingdata = os.path.join("C:\work\work-space\Data", "ml-1m", "ratings.dat")
    ratingdata=sc.textFile(ratingdata)
    racollect = ratingdata.map(lambda a : a.split("::")[2])
    racollect2 = racollect.map(lambda a : (a,1)).reduceByKey(lambda a,b : a+b).sortBy(lambda a : a[1],ascending=False)
    head = sc.parallelize(["Id, No.views"])
    totalview= head.union(racollect2)
    totalview.saveAsTextFile("C:\work\work-space\Data\out1")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the number of partitions in RDD, if it's more than one then you have to `coalesce` the partitions into one. This operation is normally slower than saving into multiple files, as the parallel saving won't work with coalesce(1) setting.

```py
# Check number of partitions in rdd
print(data.rdd.getNumberPartitions())

# Coalesce it, this function adjust the number partition count.
data.rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("./your_file")
```